# higher order procedure to print alternating pictures

Tags: scheme, racket

***definition of task*** : i have to make pumpkins and fishes hanging on a string

***terms used :***

what-is-it?  ==>a function that determines whether to make a fish or a pumpkin

fish-squared ==> a function to make a fish using 2 parameters

pumpkin ==> a function to make a pumpkin with also 2 parameters

decorations ==> a function that appends all the images together

hang-by-thread ==> a function that hangs all the images to a thread

***extra***

for this exercise i have to use"**(if (odd? k) fish-square pumpkin))**" EXACTLY like that

***problem***

when i execute my program it takes a while and then crashes, so i suspect it of being trapped in a loop

***code*** :

```
(define (fun-string n r)
    (define (what-is-it k)
        (if (odd? k) fish-squared pumpkin))
    (define (decorations k)
        (ht-append ((what-is-it k) r r)
            (decorations (- k 1))))
    (hang-by-thread (decorations n)))
```

***goal*** :

the goal of this exercise is to learn how to pass-trough functions as parameters, something that scheme is able to do.

many thanks

EDIT*

i have added the base line, still the same problem, here is all the code :

```
(define (lampion r l)
  (vc-append (filled-rectangle 2 l) (pumpkin r)))

(define (hang-by-string pumpkins)
  (vc-append (filled-rectangle (pict-width pumpkins) 2)
             lampionnetjes))    

(define (fish-square wh l)
  (vc-append (filled-rectangle 2 l) (fish wh wh)))

(define (fun-string n r)
  (define (what-is-it k)
    (if (odd? k) fish-square pumpkin))
  (define (decorations k)
    (if (= k 1) fish-square)
    (ht-append ((what-is-it k) r r)
               (decorations (- k 1))))
  (hang-by-string (decorations n)))
```

Comment: Can you post **all** of the code?

Comment: That is not all of the code. And you `if` is wrong, there should be no closing bracket after pumpkin so that `ht-append` is in the else clause.

Comment: It would be appropriate for you to delete your (later) duplicate question, [I need to make a higher order procedure in scheme to hang alternatively pumpkins and fishes on a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19682559/1281433).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented [uselpa's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680797/1281433) by doing

```
(define (decorations k)
  (if (= k 1) fish-square) ; the results of this line are discarded
  (ht-append ((what-is-it k) r r)
             (decorations (- k 1))))
```

because you discard the result so of the `if` statement and return the value of

```
(ht-append ((what-is-it k) r r)
           (decorations (- k 1)))
```

just like in the original code.  The conditional has the form

```
(if test
  then-part
  else-part)
```

so what you need is

```
(define (decorations k)
  (if (= k 1)
    fish-square
    (ht-append ((what-is-it k) r r)
               (decorations (- k 1)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the base case in procedure `decorations`. You should test whether k <= 0, and stop.